# Component tree is empty and can't add any component

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just don't get it. I am following a tutorial and in the project that he opened the component tree is not empty, it has a constraint layout and a button and he also can add buttons, but in my fresh project there isn't any layout or button please help.(The layout that I chose is "Basic Activity".) [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Pb4.png)

PS:I can't add anything.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFKZE.png)

Comment: In your screenshot, towards the upper-right, you will see three buttons: Code, Split, and Design. You are currently in the Design view. Click on "Code" to switch to a text editor with the XML of the layout resource. Is there any XML in there, or is it empty?

Comment: Yes there is a xml file

Comment: OK. What exactly is in it? You might want to edit your question and show what the XML is.

Comment: I put a picture of the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Re-installing or resetting Android Studio alone didn't help. I finally solved it by also re-installing the whole Android SDK. The directories for resetting the IDE are:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.2
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview4.2
```

(or whatever version of Android Studio you're currently on)